# Operation Overloading << as a Friend in Linked List

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend

I am currently trying to learn how to implement a Doubly Linked List. I have the basis down for the nodes but am unable to actually get my program to work with Overloading Operators.

DLList.cxx:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const DLList &l) {


DLNode *p;


for (p = l.head; p != NULL && p -> next != NULL; p = p -> next)
{
    os << l;
}
return os;
}
```

header:

```
class DLNode
{
private:
int data;
DLNode *prev, *next;

public:
DLNode()
{
    next = prev = NULL;
}

DLNode(int d, DLNode *p=NULL, DLNode *n=NULL)
{
    data = d;
    prev = p;
    next = n;
}

DLNode* next_node() {
    return next;
}

DLNode* prev_node() {
    return prev;
}

friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const DLNode& n) {
    os << n.data;
    return os;
}

friend class DLList;
};



// ADT for Doubly Linked List
class DLList
{
private:
DLNode *head, *tail;

public:

DLList();           
~DLList();            

bool isEmpty();       // is this list empty?
bool isInList(int);   // is this list contain the given integer?

void addToHead(int);  // add the given integer to the head
void addToTail(int);  // add the given integer to the tail


// DO NOT call this method on empty list
int deleteHead();


// DO NOT call this method on empty list
int deleteTail();


void removeAll();


// append the given list at the end of this list
void append(const DLList& dll);


// output each elemen t in this list to 'os'
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const DLList& l);


// read an integer from 'is'
// and add it to the tail of this list
friend istream& operator>> (istream& is, DLList& l);
};
```

My Question is why i am getting the following error stating "next" still protected from the overloaded function?

```
    In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const DLList&)':
DLList.cpp:90:40: error: 'DLNode* DLNode::next' is private within this context
for (p = l.head; p != NULL && p -> next != NULL; p = p -> next){
                                    ^~~~
DLList.h:33:20: note: declared private here
 DLNode *prev, *next;
                ^~~~
DLList.cpp:90:63: error: 'DLNode* DLNode::next' is private within this context
 for (p = l.head; p != NULL && p -> next != NULL; p = p -> next){
                                                           ^~~~
DLList.h:33:20: note: declared private here
 DLNode *prev, *next;
```

It was declared a friend, and DLList is a friend of DLNode. And because its a Friend Class i cant Do DLList::DLNode. Is there something i am missing?

My first thoughts were it had something to do with my prototype but was unsure. Any guidance would be appreciated. Note, I am also have a similar problem with istream but one should fix the other.

Comment: By *it*, I presume you mean the compiler? When asking about a compiler error, you should include the **exact** error message in your question. It's on the screen right in front of you, and there's absolutely no reason for you to not give us that information as well. You're asking for *free help* to solve *your problem*; it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to do so by including the details you already have.

Comment: As @KenWhite has pointed out, an exact error message would help solve the problem. On eyeballing the code, I think that declaring `DLList` a `friend` of `DLNode` would solve your problem. As the code stands, the overloaded `operator <<` for `DLList` still has no way to access private members of `DLNode`, which `DLNode::next` is.

Comment: `operator<<` is a `friend` of `DLList`, but I see no signs  if it being a `friend` of `DLNode`, and `DLNode` contains `next`.

Comment: Personally, I would make `DLNode` a `struct` and hide it  inside `DLList`. There is no need for it to be nearly that smart or exposed to `DLList`'s clients.

Comment: Friendship is NOT transitive. `operator<<(std::ostream&, const DLList&)` is a friend of `DLList`, and `DLList` is a friend of `DLNode`, but this does not mean that `operator<<(std::ostream&, const DLList&)` is a friend of `DLNode`.

Comment: Forgive me @KenWhite this is my first time posting of any sort of website like this. Normally i can generate  a solution based on info online but was unable to do so. The error is "DLNode* DLNode::next' is private within this context".

Comment: Don't add details or information relevant to the question in comments. Instead, [edit] to add them to your question instead where they can be seen. (On every question or answer here, there is an [edit] link. In the case of a question, it's below the tags. In an answer, it's along the lower edge of the post.) I also believe there is more information than that in the error; there is usually an error message or code, and a line number. Post the **entire, exact message**.

Comment: I hope i changed the post in the correct format, thank you very much @KenWhite for pointing them out and helping. I was unaware Friendship wasnt Transitive either. However wouldnt that be poor etiquette to have a both Class declared friends of each other?

Answer (score 0):

The `next` and `prev` members of `DLNode` are private, so they are only accessible to `DLNode` itself, and its `friend`s.

The error messages are because your `operator<<` for `DLList` is not a `friend` of `DLNode`.  It is a `friend` of `DLList` instead.  Friendship is not inherited.  `DLList` is a `friend` of `DLNode`, but `operator<<` for `DLList` is not.

In `operator<<` for `DLList`, the test for `&& p->next != NULL` in the `for` loop causes the loop to NOT output the `tail` node of the list.  You don't need that check at all, get rid of it. The loop should be checking only `p` for `NULL`.  That would fix the logic bug, and get rid of one of the compiler errors.  To get rid of the other error, use the public `DLNode::next_node()` method instead of accessing `next` directly:

```
for (DLNode *p = l.head; p != NULL; p = p->next_node())
```

Once you fix those errors, your loop will still not output correctly.  You defined a separate `operator<<` for `DLNode`, but are not actually calling it.  It takes a `const DLNode &` as input, but you are passing a `DLNode*` to `operator<<`, which will call `std::ostream::operator<<(void*)` instead.  You need to dereference the `DLNode*` pointer in order to invoke your `operator<<` for `DLNode`:

```
os << *l;
```